# Can you read/write to the registry without administrative permissions?

Tags: vb.net, registry

Essentially I need somewhere to store an expiration date for my software and do not want this to be accidentally deleted (the likelihood of anyone tampering with my software is relatively minimal). I thought about writing this to the registry, however this appears to require administrative permissions. Is there any way to get around this issue?

Thanks

Comment: where (what hive) are you trying to write to?  Apps change/set file associations and save settings to the registry all the time.

Comment: Like most things in Windows that are subject to user privileges, there are areas that require administrative privileges and those that don't. Without specifics of where (which hive of the registry) you're trying to access, it's impossible to say whether administrative privileges are required or not.

Answer (score 0):

The better alternative would be to use [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you really need to modify the registry, and you don't have sufficient privileges to do so, you would need to either ask for an administrator's credentials, so you could temporary elevate your privileges, or you would need to make a request to another process, such as a service, which is already running under another account with sufficient privileges.

If Isolated Storage is a bigger tool than you need for the job, another simpler option would be to use an App.config setting.  You can create a setting in your project properties designer screen, and then you can read/write the setting via `My.Settings`.